# Object Oriented PHP how it implement?

Tags: php

I'm novice for PHP object Oriented Programming and confuse in following

i have a class "**Customer**" (**customer.php**) which has methods "**display_registration_form()**" and "**add_cutomer()**". the method "display_registration_form()" has code for the form to echo in order to display that form. 
when user fills and submit that form, i need to send the data to "add_cutomer()" method which has SQL to add that data to the database.

but how to call that function? in procedural way it is easy to send data to the script where the method is defined and then call the method...but in this the script has a class!
so i think to define an other PHP script something "add_cutomer.php", instantiate an object from the class file, then call the method "add_customer()".

```
         **form ----> add_cutomer.php <--------- customer.php (class)**
```

this solution learns me that in implementing OO in PHP, create the class file and create separate file(which is not a class just instantiate an object from the class) when using method of that class. May i know that, *is it the correct way to implement or is there another if this is incorrect?*

thanking you

regards

pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read up on the basics of object oriented PHP programming using some of the free tutorials available throughtout the net. Here are a few a good places to start:

http://www.php.net/oop5.basic

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

customer.php

```
class Customer{
    function display_registration_form(){
        // Here is your function
        }
}
```

callfunction.php

```
$db = new Customer();
$registration = $db->display_registration_form();
echo $registration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, if you intend to code using OOP, a class method is not a good way to do it, it does not comply with MVC, also you can not manage the output format and the used theme.

However, this is a good thing to create and instantiate objects with this class.
You should understand there is 2 types of methods in OOP, the class methods and the instance methods, the first ones is also called static methods in PHP.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Then, make sure you understand that instantiate a SQL object and create it very different, you will have 2 different static methods.

Finally, there are many PHP frameworks that implements OOP in a good way, i advise you to use one of them.